# Как быстро залить проект написаный на yii2 на хостинг?

Tags: yii2, файлы, хостинг

Создал сайт на PHP-фреймворке yii2 и теперь нужно залить его на хостинг. Возможно это сделать побыстрее чем тупо перекинуть ядро фреймворка и все его файлы через FTP-менеджер? Если что использую хостинг Hostinger

Comment: А зачем перекидывать ядро? Можно просто загрузить ваши файлы и выполнить **composer install**.

Comment: Залить архив на сервер одним файлом и распаковать.

Comment: @InnoT20 Где именно выполнить этот **composer install**

Comment: @Olexandr папку vendor заливать не обязательно. После того как вы загрузили ваш проект на сервер. Вам нужно перейти в папку со своим проектом и выполнить **composer install**. Если компосер не установлен, то вы можете скачать его **curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php** и выполнить **composer.phar install**.

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас VDS сервер, то сделайте, как отписали выше - в корневой директории сервера выполните **composer install** и потом перекиньте только те файлы, которые вы создавали или правили. Если обычный сервер и единственный доступ через панель хостинга типо cPanel или что там стоит, то там есть возможность загрузить архив и распаковать на сервере, тоже в разы быстрее чем по FTP пофайлово заливать